# ob_release_environment variable is not defined

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm working on creating OneBranch YAML release pipelines. I used their tool to auto-generate a YAML file which looks something like this:

```
trigger: none

variables:
  ob_release_environment: PPE

resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: templates
    type: git
    name: OneBranch.Pipelines/GovernedTemplates
    ref: refs/heads/main

  pipelines:
  - pipeline: _MyPipeline
    trigger: none
    source: MyPipeline
    project: One

extends:
  template: v2/OneBranch.NonOfficial.CrossPlat.yml@templates
  parameters:
    stages:
    - stage: Deploy_Service
      displayName: Deploy Service
      jobs:
      - job: agent_job
        displayName: Agent job
        pool:
          type: release
        steps:
        - download: _MyPipeline
```

This is the template where the error is coming from (`OneBranch.Release.NonProd.Stage.yml@templates`):

```
parameters:
- name: stage
  type: stage

- name: featureFlags
  type: object
  default: {}

- name: onebranchToolsetTag
  type: string

- name: ev2ManagedSdpRolloutConfig
  type: object
  default: {}

- name: customTags
  type: string
  default: ""

- name: containers
  type: object

- name: mainPool
  type: object

- name: allowedNonReleaseTasks
  type: object
  default:
    - xyz@1 # Download alias/keyword for downloading pipeline artifacts
    - DownloadPipelineArtifact@2 # Download Pipeline artifacts task (latest version)
    - VSTest@3 # Allow running tests. This is needed especially for the integration tests.
    - PublishTestResults@2 # Allow publishing test results.
    - VisualStudioTestPlatformInstaller@1 # Allow VSTest platform installer

stages:

- stage: ${{ parameters.stage.stage }}
  displayName: ${{ parameters.stage.displayName }}
  ${{ if parameters.stage.dependsOn }}:
    dependsOn: ${{ parameters.stage.dependsOn }}
  ${{ if ne(parameters.stage.condition, '') }}:
    condition: ${{ parameters.stage.condition }}
  variables:
  - ${{ if ne(parameters.stage.variables, '') }}:
    - ${{ each v in parameters.stage.variables }}:
      - ${{ if ne(v.key, '') }}:
        - name: ${{ v.key }}
          value: ${{ v.value }}
      - ${{ else }}:
        - ${{ insert }}: ${{ v }}

  - name: runCodesignValidationInjection
    value: false

  - name: skipComponentGovernanceDetection
    value: true

  - name: skipNugetSecurityAnalysis
    value: true

  - name: Codeql.SkipTaskAutoInjection
    value: true

  - template: ../../Jobs/Prepipeline_Validation_Vars.yml
    parameters:
      buildType: buddy
      featureFlags: ${{ parameters.featureFlags }} # skipPoliciesValidation parsed from featureFlags
      pipelineType: 'onebranchrelease'

  # Check for featureFlag before doing any validations for Ev2 RA
  - ${{if eq(parameters.featureFlags.ev2managedsdpsupport, true)}}:
  # Set these variables when Ev2 RA task is involved so that we can do required validations based on this later i.e only one cloud per stage when Ev2 RA task is used
  # This will set a variable per cloud that contains the last stage defined in user yaml for that cloud

    - ${{ each job in parameters.stage.jobs }}:
      - ${{ if eq(contains(convertToJSON(job.steps.*.task), 'Ev2RARollout@2'), true)}}: # if job contains ev2 ra task
        - name: LastJobWithEv2RATask
          value: ${{job.job }}

    - ${{ if eq(contains(convertToJSON(parameters.stage.jobs.*.steps.*.inputs.TaskAction), 'RegisterAndRollout'), true) }}:
      - name: IsRegisterAndRollout
        value: true

    - ${{ if eq(contains(convertToJSON(parameters.stage.jobs.*.steps.*.inputs.TaskAction), 'RegisterOnly'), true) }}:
      - name: IsRegisterOnly
        value: true


  jobs:

      # Check for Ev2 RA + Managed SDP Rollout parameters when featureflag exists
    - ${{ if eq(parameters.featureFlags.ev2managedsdpsupport, true)}}:
      - ${{ if eq(contains(convertToJSON(parameters.stage.jobs.*.steps.*.task), 'Ev2RARollout@2'), true) }}:
        - ${{ if eq(contains(convertToJSON(parameters.stage.jobs.*.steps.*.inputs.TaskAction), 'RegisterAndRollout'), true) }}:
          - ${{ if eq(parameters.ev2ManagedSdpRolloutConfig.rolloutType, '') }}:
            - 'ev2ManagedSdpRolloutConfig with rolloutType is required for Ev2RARollout@2 task. Please include it as a parameter to the governed template. Allowed values are normal, emergency and globaloutage': error

          - ${{ if eq(parameters.ev2ManagedSdpRolloutConfig.overrideManagedValidationDuration, '') }}:
            - 'overrideManagedValidationDuration is required for Ev2RARollout@2 task. Please include it as a parameter to the governed template. Allowed values are true, false. Set it to false if you want to use default values': error

          - ${{ if eq(parameters.ev2ManagedSdpRolloutConfig.managedValidationOverrideDurationInHours, '') }}:
            - 'managedValidationOverrideDurationInHours is required for Ev2RARollout@2 task. Please include it as a parameter to the governed template and set it to a valid number. Set it to 0 if you want to use default values and not overriding them': error

          - ${{ if eq(parameters.ev2ManagedSdpRolloutConfig.icmIncidentId, '') }}:
            - 'ev2ManagedSdpRolloutConfig.icmIncidentId is required for Ev2RARollout@2 task. For globaloutage rollouts, it must be a valid number. For emergency rollouts it is optional.Set it to 0 if you are not specififying an incident ID for normal/emergency rollouts.': error

          - ${{ if and(ne(parameters.ev2ManagedSdpRolloutConfig.rolloutType, ''), ne(parameters.ev2ManagedSdpRolloutConfig.rolloutType, 'normal'), ne(parameters.ev2ManagedSdpRolloutConfig.rolloutType, 'emergency'), ne(parameters.ev2ManagedSdpRolloutConfig.rolloutType, 'globaloutage')) }}:
            - 'ev2ManagedSdpRolloutConfig.rolloutType ${{ parameters.ev2ManagedSdpRolloutConfig.rolloutType }} is not supported. Supported types: normal, emergency, globaloutage': error

          - ${{ if and(ne(parameters.ev2ManagedSdpRolloutConfig.overrideManagedValidationDuration, ''), ne(parameters.ev2ManagedSdpRolloutConfig.overrideManagedValidationDuration, true), ne(parameters.ev2ManagedSdpRolloutConfig.overrideManagedValidationDuration, false)) }}:
            - 'ev2ManagedSdpRolloutConfig.overrideManagedValidationDuration ${{ parameters.ev2ManagedSdpRolloutConfig.overrideManagedValidationDuration }} is not supported. Supported values: true, false': error

          - ${{ if and(eq(parameters.ev2ManagedSdpRolloutConfig.rolloutType, 'globaloutage'), le(parameters.ev2ManagedSdpRolloutConfig.icmIncidentId, 0) ) }}:            
              - 'ev2ManagedSdpRolloutConfig.icmIncidentId should be a valid integer > 0 representing an Incident ID for globaloutage rollouts': error

          - ${{ if and(eq(parameters.ev2ManagedSdpRolloutConfig.rolloutType, 'normal'),eq(parameters.ev2ManagedSdpRolloutConfig.overrideManagedValidationDuration, true),  ne(parameters.ev2ManagedSdpRolloutConfig.managedValidationOverrideDurationInHours, '') , gt(24, parameters.ev2ManagedSdpRolloutConfig.managedValidationOverrideDurationInHours)) }}:
            - 'ev2ManagedSdpRolloutConfig.managedValidationOverrideDurationInHours ${{ parameters.ev2ManagedSdpRolloutConfig.managedValidationOverrideDurationInHours }} is not supported for normal rollouts. Supported values: >= 24 when overrideManagedValidationDuration is set to true': error

          - ${{ if and(eq(parameters.ev2ManagedSdpRolloutConfig.rolloutType, 'emergency'), eq(parameters.ev2ManagedSdpRolloutConfig.overrideManagedValidationDuration, true), ne(parameters.ev2ManagedSdpRolloutConfig.managedValidationOverrideDurationInHours, ''), gt(1, parameters.ev2ManagedSdpRolloutConfig.managedValidationOverrideDurationInHours)) }}:
            - 'ev2ManagedSdpRolloutConfig.managedValidationOverrideDurationInHours ${{ parameters.ev2ManagedSdpRolloutConfig.managedValidationOverrideDurationInHours }} is not supported for emergency rollouts. Supported values: >= 1 when overrideManagedValidationDuration is set to true': error

          - ${{ if and(eq(parameters.ev2ManagedSdpRolloutConfig.rolloutType, 'globaloutage'),eq(parameters.ev2ManagedSdpRolloutConfig.overrideManagedValidationDuration, true), ne(parameters.ev2ManagedSdpRolloutConfig.managedValidationOverrideDurationInHours, ''), gt(0, parameters.ev2ManagedSdpRolloutConfig.managedValidationOverrideDurationInHours)) }}:
            - 'ev2ManagedSdpRolloutConfig.managedValidationOverrideDurationInHours ${{ parameters.ev2ManagedSdpRolloutConfig.managedValidationOverrideDurationInHours }} is not supported for globaloutage rollouts. Supported values: >= 0 when overrideManagedValidationDuration is set to true': error


    - ${{ if eq(variables.ob_release_environment, '') }}:
      - 'Stage variable ob_release_environment is not defined': error

    - ${{ if and(eq(variables.ob_release_usedeploymentjob, true), eq(variables.ob_deploymentjob_environment,'')) }}:
      - 'ob_deploymentjob_environment is required when ob_release_usedeploymentjob is set to true': error

    - ${{ if and(not(eq(variables.ob_release_environment, 'PPE')), not(eq(variables.ob_release_environment, 'Test'))) }}:
      - 'Value $(variables.ob_release_environment) is not supported. Supported values are PPE, Test': error

    - ${{if and(eq(variables.ob_release_environment, 'PPE'), not(startswith(parameters.stage.stage, 'PPE_')))}}  :
      - 'Release environment PPE has to match with stage prefix PPE_. Current stage name is ${{parameters.stage.stage}}': error

    - ${{if and(eq(variables.ob_release_environment, 'Test'), not(startswith(parameters.stage.stage, 'Test_')))}}  :
      - 'Release environment Test has to match with stage prefix Test_. Current stage name is ${{parameters.stage.stage}}': error


    # Ev2 RA related validations for Test/PPE

    - ${{if eq(parameters.featureFlags.ev2managedsdpsupport, true)}}:

      - ${{ each job in parameters.stage.jobs }}:
        - ${{ if and(eq(contains(convertToJSON(job.steps.*.task), 'Ev2RARollout@2'), true), ne(variables.LastJobWithEv2RATask, job.job))}}: # if job contains ev2 ra task
          - 'stage ${{parameters.stage.stage}} can have only one job containing Ev2 RA Task. It is already part of another job ${{variables.LastJobWithEv2RATask}}': error


    - job: PreReleaseValidation
      pool:
        ${{ if and( eq(variables['System.TeamProjectId'], 'teamProjectId'), eq(parameters.featureFlags.useValidationPool, true) ) }}:
          name: OneBranchPipelines-Validation
        ${{ if or( ne(variables['System.TeamProjectId'], 'teamProjectId'), ne(parameters.featureFlags.useValidationPool, true) ) }}:
          name: OneBranchPipelines
        HostTenant: AME
        Host: windows

      steps:
        - checkout: none
        - task: onebranch.pipeline.prebuildvalidation${{ parameters.onebranchToolsetTag }}@1
          name: prepipelinevalidation
          displayName: ' PrePipeline Validation'
          inputs:
            cdpBuildType: buddy
            skipOfficialValidation: false
            skipPoliciesValidation:  ${{ parameters.featureFlags.skipPoliciesValidation }}
            pipelineType: 'onebranchrelease'

        - task: onebranch.pipeline.containertelemetry@1
          displayName: ' Container Telemetry'
          continueOnError: true

        - script: |
            echo ##vso[build.addbuildtag]onebranch_release_yaml
            echo ##vso[build.addbuildtag]onebranch_release_${{ variables.ob_release_environment }}
          displayName: ' Setup Tags for Audit'

        - ${{ if eq(parameters.featureFlags.pushMetrics, true) }}:
            - task: onebranch.pipeline.metrics${{ parameters.onebranchToolsetTag }}@2
              displayName: " Push Metrics V2"
              condition: always()



    - ${{ each job in parameters.stage.jobs }}:
      - ${{ if and(ne(job.pool.type, 'release'), ne(job.pool.type, 'server'), ne(job.pool.type, 'windows'), ne(job.pool.type, 'linux'))}}:
        - 'Job type pool type ${{ job.pool.type }} is not supported inside a release stage. Supported pool types: release, server': error

      - ${{ if and(eq(job.pool.type, 'release'), ne(variables.ob_release_usedeploymentjob, true)) }}:
          - template: ../../Jobs/Release.NonProd.Job.yml
            parameters:
              ReleaseEnvironment: ${{ variables.ob_release_environment }}
              job: ${{ job }}
              featureFlags: ${{parameters.featureFlags}}
              onebranchToolsetTag: ${{ parameters.onebranchToolsetTag }}
              ev2ManagedSdpRolloutConfig: ${{ parameters.ev2ManagedSdpRolloutConfig }}

      - ${{ if and(eq(job.pool.type, 'release'), eq(variables.ob_release_usedeploymentjob, true)) }}:
        - template: ../../Jobs/Release.NonProd.DeploymentJob.yml
          parameters:
            ReleaseEnvironment: ${{ variables.ob_release_environment }}
            DeploymentJobEnvironment: ${{ variables.ob_deploymentjob_environment }}
            job: ${{ job }}
            featureFlags: ${{parameters.featureFlags}}
            onebranchToolsetTag: ${{ parameters.onebranchToolsetTag }}
            ev2ManagedSdpRolloutConfig: ${{ parameters.ev2ManagedSdpRolloutConfig }}

      - ${{ if and(eq(job.pool.type, 'server'), ne(variables.ob_release_usedeploymentjob, true) ) }}:
        - template: ../../Jobs/Server.Agentless.Release.Job.yml
          parameters:
            serverjob: ${{ job }}
            featureFlags: ${{parameters.featureFlags}}
            ReleaseEnvironment: ${{ variables.ob_release_environment }}

      - ${{ elseif and(eq(job.pool.type, 'server'), eq(variables.ob_release_usedeploymentjob, true) ) }}:
        - template: ../../Jobs/Server.Agentless.Release.DeploymentJob.yml
          parameters:
            serverjob: ${{ job }}
            featureFlags: ${{parameters.featureFlags}}
            ReleaseEnvironment: ${{ variables.ob_release_environment }}
            DeploymentJobEnvironment: ${{ variables.ob_deploymentjob_environment }}

      - ${{ elseif or(eq(job.pool.type, 'windows'), eq(job.pool.type, 'linux')) }}:
        - ${{each step in job.steps}}:
          - ${{if eq(containsValue(parameters.allowedNonReleaseTasks, step.task), false)}}:
            - "${{step.task}} is not part of allowed tasks list in windows/linux job under the release stage. Only the following tasks are allowed - Download alias, DownloadPipelineArtifact@2, VSTest@3, PublishTestResults@2 and VisualStudioTestPlatformInstaller@1."

        - ${{ if and(eq(job.pool.type, 'windows'), eq(job.pool.isCustom, true) ) }}:
            template: ../../Jobs/Windows.Custom.Job.yml
          ${{ elseif and(eq(job.pool.type, 'linux'), eq(job.pool.isCustom, true) ) }}:
            template: ../../Jobs/Linux.Custom.Job.yml
          parameters:
            parentStage: ${{ parameters.stage.stage }}
            job: ${{ job }}
            featureFlags: ${{ parameters.featureFlags }}
            sdlExtensionPrefix: securedevelopmentteam.vss-secure-development-tools
            onebranchToolsetTag: ${{ parameters.onebranchToolsetTag }}
            customTags: ${{ parameters.customTags }}
            containers: ${{ parameters.containers }}
            mainPool: ${{ parameters.mainPool }}
            ${{ if eq(job.pool.isCustom, true) }}:
              isOfficial: false
            runOnHost: ${{ coalesce(parameters.featureFlags.runOnHost, job.pool.runOnHost, false) }}
            targets:
              ${{ if eq(coalesce(parameters.featureFlags.runOnHost, job.pool.runOnHost, false), true) }}:
                generic: host
              ${{ elseif eq(job.pool.type, 'windows') }}:
                generic: windows_onebranch_container
              ${{ elseif and(eq(job.pool.type, 'linux'), eq(job.pool.hostArchitecture, 'arm64')) }}:
                generic: linux_arm64_onebranch_container
              ${{ else }}:
                generic: linux_onebranch_container
```

My issue is that I'm getting a validation error when I try to run this pipeline:

```
/v2/Stages/OneBranch/OneBranch.Release.NonProd.Stage.yml@templates (Line: 127, Col: 9): Unexpected value 'Stage variable ob_release_environment is not defined'
/v2/Stages/OneBranch/OneBranch.Release.NonProd.Stage.yml@templates (Line: 133, Col: 9): Unexpected value 'Value $(variables.ob_release_environment) is not supported. Supported values are PPE, Test'
```

How do I fix this? I'm defining the variable ob_release_environment. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is the OneBranch YAML tool?

Comment: I'm not familiar with a tool called OneBranch either. This looks like a standard Azure Pipelines YAML. If this is in-house tooling, I'd recommend starting by discussing the problem with the team who owns the tooling. The likely cause of the problem is that you're defining that variable at a scope that can't be resolved within the template. Did you try defining the variable within the `Deploy_Service` stage?

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce the same issue when using the similar YAML sample.

[image]

The cause of the issue is that the if expression will expand at compile time. But the Pipeline variable is not able to pass to yaml template at compile time.

To solve this issue, you can add the parameter in the YAML template.

```
parameters:
- name: ob_release_environment
  type: string
```

You can use the parameters in the if expression.

For example:

```
- ${{ if eq(parameters.ob_release_environment, '') }}:
  - 'Stage variable ob_release_environment is not defined': error
```

And then you can pass the variable value to template with the format: `${{variables.ob_release_environment}}`

For example:

```
trigger: none

variables:
  ob_release_environment: PPE

resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: templates
    type: git
    name: OneBranch.Pipelines/GovernedTemplates
    ref: refs/heads/main

  pipelines:
  - pipeline: _MyPipeline
    trigger: none
    source: MyPipeline
    project: One

extends:
  template: v2/OneBranch.NonOfficial.CrossPlat.yml@templates
  parameters:
    ob_release_environment: ${{variables.ob_release_environment}}
    stages:
    - stage: Deploy_Service
      displayName: Deploy Service
      jobs:
      - job: agent_job
        displayName: Agent job
        pool:
          type: release
        steps:
        - download: _MyPipeline
```

**Template:**

```
parameters:
- name: ob_release_environment
  type: string

- name: stage
  type: stage

- name: featureFlags
  type: object
  default: {}

- name: onebranchToolsetTag
  type: string

- name: ev2ManagedSdpRolloutConfig
  type: object
  default: {}

- name: customTags
  type: string
  default: ""

- name: containers
  type: object

- name: mainPool
  type: object

- name: allowedNonReleaseTasks
  type: object
  default:
    - xyz@1 # Download alias/keyword for downloading pipeline artifacts
    - DownloadPipelineArtifact@2 # Download Pipeline artifacts task (latest version)
    - VSTest@3 # Allow running tests. This is needed especially for the integration tests.
    - PublishTestResults@2 # Allow publishing test results.
    - VisualStudioTestPlatformInstaller@1 # Allow VSTest platform installer

stages:

- stage: ${{ parameters.stage.stage }}
  displayName: ${{ parameters.stage.displayName }}
  ${{ if parameters.stage.dependsOn }}:
    dependsOn: ${{ parameters.stage.dependsOn }}
  ${{ if ne(parameters.stage.condition, '') }}:
    condition: ${{ parameters.stage.condition }}
  variables:
  - ${{ if ne(parameters.stage.variables, '') }}:
    - ${{ each v in parameters.stage.variables }}:
      - ${{ if ne(v.key, '') }}:
        - name: ${{ v.key }}
          value: ${{ v.value }}
      - ${{ else }}:
        - ${{ insert }}: ${{ v }}

  - name: runCodesignValidationInjection
    value: false

  - name: skipComponentGovernanceDetection
    value: true

  - name: skipNugetSecurityAnalysis
    value: true

  - name: Codeql.SkipTaskAutoInjection
    value: true

  - template: ../../Jobs/Prepipeline_Validation_Vars.yml
    parameters:
      buildType: buddy
      featureFlags: ${{ parameters.featureFlags }} # skipPoliciesValidation parsed from featureFlags
      pipelineType: 'onebranchrelease'

  # Check for featureFlag before doing any validations for Ev2 RA
  - ${{if eq(parameters.featureFlags.ev2managedsdpsupport, true)}}:
  # Set these variables when Ev2 RA task is involved so that we can do required validations based on this later i.e only one cloud per stage when Ev2 RA task is used
  # This will set a variable per cloud that contains the last stage defined in user yaml for that cloud

    - ${{ each job in parameters.stage.jobs }}:
      - ${{ if eq(contains(convertToJSON(job.steps.*.task), 'Ev2RARollout@2'), true)}}: # if job contains ev2 ra task
        - name: LastJobWithEv2RATask
          value: ${{job.job }}

    - ${{ if eq(contains(convertToJSON(parameters.stage.jobs.*.steps.*.inputs.TaskAction), 'RegisterAndRollout'), true) }}:
      - name: IsRegisterAndRollout
        value: true

    - ${{ if eq(contains(convertToJSON(parameters.stage.jobs.*.steps.*.inputs.TaskAction), 'RegisterOnly'), true) }}:
      - name: IsRegisterOnly
        value: true


  jobs:

      # Check for Ev2 RA + Managed SDP Rollout parameters when featureflag exists
    - ${{ if eq(parameters.featureFlags.ev2managedsdpsupport, true)}}:
      - ${{ if eq(contains(convertToJSON(parameters.stage.jobs.*.steps.*.task), 'Ev2RARollout@2'), true) }}:
        - ${{ if eq(contains(convertToJSON(parameters.stage.jobs.*.steps.*.inputs.TaskAction), 'RegisterAndRollout'), true) }}:
          - ${{ if eq(parameters.ev2ManagedSdpRolloutConfig.rolloutType, '') }}:
            - 'ev2ManagedSdpRolloutConfig with rolloutType is required for Ev2RARollout@2 task. Please include it as a parameter to the governed template. Allowed values are normal, emergency and globaloutage': error

          - ${{ if eq(parameters.ev2ManagedSdpRolloutConfig.overrideManagedValidationDuration, '') }}:
            - 'overrideManagedValidationDuration is required for Ev2RARollout@2 task. Please include it as a parameter to the governed template. Allowed values are true, false. Set it to false if you want to use default values': error

          - ${{ if eq(parameters.ev2ManagedSdpRolloutConfig.managedValidationOverrideDurationInHours, '') }}:
            - 'managedValidationOverrideDurationInHours is required for Ev2RARollout@2 task. Please include it as a parameter to the governed template and set it to a valid number. Set it to 0 if you want to use default values and not overriding them': error

          - ${{ if eq(parameters.ev2ManagedSdpRolloutConfig.icmIncidentId, '') }}:
            - 'ev2ManagedSdpRolloutConfig.icmIncidentId is required for Ev2RARollout@2 task. For globaloutage rollouts, it must be a valid number. For emergency rollouts it is optional.Set it to 0 if you are not specififying an incident ID for normal/emergency rollouts.': error

          - ${{ if and(ne(parameters.ev2ManagedSdpRolloutConfig.rolloutType, ''), ne(parameters.ev2ManagedSdpRolloutConfig.rolloutType, 'normal'), ne(parameters.ev2ManagedSdpRolloutConfig.rolloutType, 'emergency'), ne(parameters.ev2ManagedSdpRolloutConfig.rolloutType, 'globaloutage')) }}:
            - 'ev2ManagedSdpRolloutConfig.rolloutType ${{ parameters.ev2ManagedSdpRolloutConfig.rolloutType }} is not supported. Supported types: normal, emergency, globaloutage': error

          - ${{ if and(ne(parameters.ev2ManagedSdpRolloutConfig.overrideManagedValidationDuration, ''), ne(parameters.ev2ManagedSdpRolloutConfig.overrideManagedValidationDuration, true), ne(parameters.ev2ManagedSdpRolloutConfig.overrideManagedValidationDuration, false)) }}:
            - 'ev2ManagedSdpRolloutConfig.overrideManagedValidationDuration ${{ parameters.ev2ManagedSdpRolloutConfig.overrideManagedValidationDuration }} is not supported. Supported values: true, false': error

          - ${{ if and(eq(parameters.ev2ManagedSdpRolloutConfig.rolloutType, 'globaloutage'), le(parameters.ev2ManagedSdpRolloutConfig.icmIncidentId, 0) ) }}:            
              - 'ev2ManagedSdpRolloutConfig.icmIncidentId should be a valid integer > 0 representing an Incident ID for globaloutage rollouts': error

          - ${{ if and(eq(parameters.ev2ManagedSdpRolloutConfig.rolloutType, 'normal'),eq(parameters.ev2ManagedSdpRolloutConfig.overrideManagedValidationDuration, true),  ne(parameters.ev2ManagedSdpRolloutConfig.managedValidationOverrideDurationInHours, '') , gt(24, parameters.ev2ManagedSdpRolloutConfig.managedValidationOverrideDurationInHours)) }}:
            - 'ev2ManagedSdpRolloutConfig.managedValidationOverrideDurationInHours ${{ parameters.ev2ManagedSdpRolloutConfig.managedValidationOverrideDurationInHours }} is not supported for normal rollouts. Supported values: >= 24 when overrideManagedValidationDuration is set to true': error

          - ${{ if and(eq(parameters.ev2ManagedSdpRolloutConfig.rolloutType, 'emergency'), eq(parameters.ev2ManagedSdpRolloutConfig.overrideManagedValidationDuration, true), ne(parameters.ev2ManagedSdpRolloutConfig.managedValidationOverrideDurationInHours, ''), gt(1, parameters.ev2ManagedSdpRolloutConfig.managedValidationOverrideDurationInHours)) }}:
            - 'ev2ManagedSdpRolloutConfig.managedValidationOverrideDurationInHours ${{ parameters.ev2ManagedSdpRolloutConfig.managedValidationOverrideDurationInHours }} is not supported for emergency rollouts. Supported values: >= 1 when overrideManagedValidationDuration is set to true': error

          - ${{ if and(eq(parameters.ev2ManagedSdpRolloutConfig.rolloutType, 'globaloutage'),eq(parameters.ev2ManagedSdpRolloutConfig.overrideManagedValidationDuration, true), ne(parameters.ev2ManagedSdpRolloutConfig.managedValidationOverrideDurationInHours, ''), gt(0, parameters.ev2ManagedSdpRolloutConfig.managedValidationOverrideDurationInHours)) }}:
            - 'ev2ManagedSdpRolloutConfig.managedValidationOverrideDurationInHours ${{ parameters.ev2ManagedSdpRolloutConfig.managedValidationOverrideDurationInHours }} is not supported for globaloutage rollouts. Supported values: >= 0 when overrideManagedValidationDuration is set to true': error


    - ${{ if eq(parameters.ob_release_environment, '') }}:
      - 'Stage variable ob_release_environment is not defined': error

    - ${{ if and(eq(variables.ob_release_usedeploymentjob, true), eq(variables.ob_deploymentjob_environment,'')) }}:
      - 'ob_deploymentjob_environment is required when ob_release_usedeploymentjob is set to true': error

    - ${{ if and(not(eq(parameters.ob_release_environment, 'PPE')), not(eq(parameters.ob_release_environment, 'Test'))) }}:
      - 'Value $(variables.ob_release_environment) is not supported. Supported values are PPE, Test': error

    - ${{if and(eq(parameters.ob_release_environment, 'PPE'), not(startswith(parameters.stage.stage, 'PPE_')))}}  :
      - 'Release environment PPE has to match with stage prefix PPE_. Current stage name is ${{parameters.stage.stage}}': error

    - ${{if and(eq(parameters.ob_release_environment, 'Test'), not(startswith(parameters.stage.stage, 'Test_')))}}  :
      - 'Release environment Test has to match with stage prefix Test_. Current stage name is ${{parameters.stage.stage}}': error


    # Ev2 RA related validations for Test/PPE

    - ${{if eq(parameters.featureFlags.ev2managedsdpsupport, true)}}:

      - ${{ each job in parameters.stage.jobs }}:
        - ${{ if and(eq(contains(convertToJSON(job.steps.*.task), 'Ev2RARollout@2'), true), ne(variables.LastJobWithEv2RATask, job.job))}}: # if job contains ev2 ra task
          - 'stage ${{parameters.stage.stage}} can have only one job containing Ev2 RA Task. It is already part of another job ${{variables.LastJobWithEv2RATask}}': error


    - job: PreReleaseValidation
      pool:
        ${{ if and( eq(variables['System.TeamProjectId'], 'teamProjectId'), eq(parameters.featureFlags.useValidationPool, true) ) }}:
          name: OneBranchPipelines-Validation
        ${{ if or( ne(variables['System.TeamProjectId'], 'teamProjectId'), ne(parameters.featureFlags.useValidationPool, true) ) }}:
          name: OneBranchPipelines
        HostTenant: AME
        Host: windows

      steps:
        - checkout: none
        - task: onebranch.pipeline.prebuildvalidation${{ parameters.onebranchToolsetTag }}@1
          name: prepipelinevalidation
          displayName: ' PrePipeline Validation'
          inputs:
            cdpBuildType: buddy
            skipOfficialValidation: false
            skipPoliciesValidation:  ${{ parameters.featureFlags.skipPoliciesValidation }}
            pipelineType: 'onebranchrelease'

        - task: onebranch.pipeline.containertelemetry@1
          displayName: ' Container Telemetry'
          continueOnError: true

        - script: |
            echo ##vso[build.addbuildtag]onebranch_release_yaml
            echo ##vso[build.addbuildtag]onebranch_release_${{ variables.ob_release_environment }}
          displayName: ' Setup Tags for Audit'

        - ${{ if eq(parameters.featureFlags.pushMetrics, true) }}:
            - task: onebranch.pipeline.metrics${{ parameters.onebranchToolsetTag }}@2
              displayName: " Push Metrics V2"
              condition: always()



    - ${{ each job in parameters.stage.jobs }}:
      - ${{ if and(ne(job.pool.type, 'release'), ne(job.pool.type, 'server'), ne(job.pool.type, 'windows'), ne(job.pool.type, 'linux'))}}:
        - 'Job type pool type ${{ job.pool.type }} is not supported inside a release stage. Supported pool types: release, server': error

      - ${{ if and(eq(job.pool.type, 'release'), ne(variables.ob_release_usedeploymentjob, true)) }}:
          - template: ../../Jobs/Release.NonProd.Job.yml
            parameters:
              ReleaseEnvironment: ${{ variables.ob_release_environment }}
              job: ${{ job }}
              featureFlags: ${{parameters.featureFlags}}
              onebranchToolsetTag: ${{ parameters.onebranchToolsetTag }}
              ev2ManagedSdpRolloutConfig: ${{ parameters.ev2ManagedSdpRolloutConfig }}

      - ${{ if and(eq(job.pool.type, 'release'), eq(variables.ob_release_usedeploymentjob, true)) }}:
        - template: ../../Jobs/Release.NonProd.DeploymentJob.yml
          parameters:
            ReleaseEnvironment: ${{ variables.ob_release_environment }}
            DeploymentJobEnvironment: ${{ variables.ob_deploymentjob_environment }}
            job: ${{ job }}
            featureFlags: ${{parameters.featureFlags}}
            onebranchToolsetTag: ${{ parameters.onebranchToolsetTag }}
            ev2ManagedSdpRolloutConfig: ${{ parameters.ev2ManagedSdpRolloutConfig }}

      - ${{ if and(eq(job.pool.type, 'server'), ne(variables.ob_release_usedeploymentjob, true) ) }}:
        - template: ../../Jobs/Server.Agentless.Release.Job.yml
          parameters:
            serverjob: ${{ job }}
            featureFlags: ${{parameters.featureFlags}}
            ReleaseEnvironment: ${{ variables.ob_release_environment }}

      - ${{ elseif and(eq(job.pool.type, 'server'), eq(variables.ob_release_usedeploymentjob, true) ) }}:
        - template: ../../Jobs/Server.Agentless.Release.DeploymentJob.yml
          parameters:
            serverjob: ${{ job }}
            featureFlags: ${{parameters.featureFlags}}
            ReleaseEnvironment: ${{ variables.ob_release_environment }}
            DeploymentJobEnvironment: ${{ variables.ob_deploymentjob_environment }}

      - ${{ elseif or(eq(job.pool.type, 'windows'), eq(job.pool.type, 'linux')) }}:
        - ${{each step in job.steps}}:
          - ${{if eq(containsValue(parameters.allowedNonReleaseTasks, step.task), false)}}:
            - "${{step.task}} is not part of allowed tasks list in windows/linux job under the release stage. Only the following tasks are allowed - Download alias, DownloadPipelineArtifact@2, VSTest@3, PublishTestResults@2 and VisualStudioTestPlatformInstaller@1."

        - ${{ if and(eq(job.pool.type, 'windows'), eq(job.pool.isCustom, true) ) }}:
            template: ../../Jobs/Windows.Custom.Job.yml
          ${{ elseif and(eq(job.pool.type, 'linux'), eq(job.pool.isCustom, true) ) }}:
            template: ../../Jobs/Linux.Custom.Job.yml
          parameters:
            parentStage: ${{ parameters.stage.stage }}
            job: ${{ job }}
            featureFlags: ${{ parameters.featureFlags }}
            sdlExtensionPrefix: securedevelopmentteam.vss-secure-development-tools
            onebranchToolsetTag: ${{ parameters.onebranchToolsetTag }}
            customTags: ${{ parameters.customTags }}
            containers: ${{ parameters.containers }}
            mainPool: ${{ parameters.mainPool }}
            ${{ if eq(job.pool.isCustom, true) }}:
              isOfficial: false
            runOnHost: ${{ coalesce(parameters.featureFlags.runOnHost, job.pool.runOnHost, false) }}
            targets:
              ${{ if eq(coalesce(parameters.featureFlags.runOnHost, job.pool.runOnHost, false), true) }}:
                generic: host
              ${{ elseif eq(job.pool.type, 'windows') }}:
                generic: windows_onebranch_container
              ${{ elseif and(eq(job.pool.type, 'linux'), eq(job.pool.hostArchitecture, 'arm64')) }}:
                generic: linux_arm64_onebranch_container
              ${{ else }}:
                generic: linux_onebranch_container
```

For more detailed info about variable format, you can refer to this doc: [Runtime expression syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#runtime-expression-syntax)

**Update:**

You can modify the generated YAML and add variable to the Stage parameter.

For example:

```
trigger: none

resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: templates
    type: git
    name: OneBranch.Pipelines/GovernedTemplates
    ref: refs/heads/main

  pipelines:
  - pipeline: _MyPipeline
    trigger: none
    source: MyPipeline
    project: One

extends:
  template: v2/OneBranch.NonOfficial.CrossPlat.yml@templates
  parameters:
    stages:
    - stage: Deploy_Service
      variables:
       ob_release_environment: PPE    
      displayName: Deploy Service
      jobs:
      - job: agent_job
        displayName: Agent job
        pool:
          type: release
        steps:
        - download: _MyPipeline
```

Comment: Hi @Kevin, thanks for taking the time to answer! The template cannot be edited as they are provided by OneBranch. Do you have any ideas on how to fix this without editing that template? Only the generated YAML can be modified

Comment: @Melissa Please refer to the update in the answer. You can try to add the variable in the stage(Deploy_Service) parameters and check if it can work.

Comment: @Melissa May I know that if the updated answer can give you some help?

Comment: Hi @Kevin, thanks for the detailed answer. This seems have changed the error, but getting a new error message: 

/v2/Stages/OneBranch/OneBranch.Release.NonProd.Stage.yml@templates (Line: 120, Col: 9): Unexpected value 'Release environment PPE has to match with stage prefix PPE_. Current stage name is Deploy_Service'

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: @Melissa Based on the error message, it seems that you need to change the stage name from **Deploy_Service** to **PPE_Deploy_Service**

Comment: I had tried that as well which gives this error 

/v2/Stages/OneBranch/OneBranch.Release.NonProd.Stage.yml@templates (Line: 111, Col: 9): Unexpected value 'Stage variable ob_release_environment is not defined'
/v2/Stages/OneBranch/OneBranch.Release.NonProd.Stage.yml@templates (Line: 117, Col: 9): Unexpected value 'Value $(variables.ob_release_environment) is not supported. Supported values are PPE, Test'